# How to setup Swagger.net development environment

Tags: c#, swagger

I have downloaded the Swagger-Net code from the Github respository(https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net)
Then i have open the solution in visualstudio and builded the code and executed the code.The server is starting but the swagger-ui is not loading on the browser after entering URL
The router works perfectly but UI is not rendering 
I have gone through the browser console i am getting following error 
1.faild to load swagger-ui-standalone-preset-js
2.faild to load swagger-ui-css
3.faild to load swagger-ui-bundle-js

Because i need to modify the code for my project requirement on the swagger-net

Kindly help how to setup the workable environment

MY CODE AVAILABLE IN "https://github.com/mydeenali/Share"

Comment: We need to see the code that sets up the swagger and some the actual code of your project.  We need to see your code.

Comment: I was uploaded my code in the above mentioned link -Darkonekt